# To compare two files and two fields - Continuation:

Tags: bash, unix, awk

Would like to compare first file field $4 with second file field $1 AND first file field $8 with second file field $3 .
Then print match cases  from first file and IF field $1 matches then print corresponding field $2 as well from second file , 
Field $3 matches then print corresponding field $4 as well from second file.

Input.csv

```
Transaction ID,Request source,User name,SendMobNum,RecMobNum,ServiceClass,Service,Amount,CreditAmount,Bonus,Process fee
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,40,2,5,2
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3
ABCD,SSS,EFG,3456,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1
ABCD,SSS,EFG,3456,9999,2345,AB,40,2,5,2
ABCD,SSS,EFG,3456,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,40,2,5,2
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3
```

master.csv

```
SendMobNum,Year,Amount,Gender 
1234,2000,30,Male
5678,2001,15,Female
2345,2002,60,Female
4567,2003
8888,2004
```

Desired Output:

```
Transaction ID,Request source,User name,SendMobNum,RecMobNum,ServiceClass,Service,Amount,CreditAmount,Bonus,Process fee,SendMobNum,Year,Amount,Gender 
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1,1234,2000,30,Male
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3,1234,2000,60,Female
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1,5678,2001,30,Male
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3,5678,2001,60,Female
```

Have tried below command and partial:

```
awk -F, '
    NR == FNR {send[$1]; amt[$3]; next} 
    FNR == 1 || ($4 in send && $8 in amt) { print $0","send[$1] ","send[$2]","amt[$3]","amt[$4]}
' master.csv Input*.csv
```

Any suggestions ...

**Edit:** Would like to treat mater.csv as two different sets of data ,

Set#1

```
SendMobNum,Year(i.e Desc of SendMobNum)
1234,2000
5678,2001
2345,2002
4567,2003
8888,2004
```

Set#2

```
Amount,Gender (i.e Desc of Amount)
30,Male
15,Female
60,Female
```

Example #1: If Input.Field$4 == 1234 and Input.Field$8==30

```
Transaction ID,Request source,User name,SendMobNum,RecMobNum,ServiceClass,Service,Amount,CreditAmount,Bonus,Process fee
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1
```

Op#1:

```
Transaction ID,Request source,User name,SendMobNum,RecMobNum,ServiceClass,Service,Amount,CreditAmount,Bonus,Process fee,SendMobNum,Year,Amount,Gender 
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1,1234,2000,30,Male
```

Example #2:If Input.Field$4 == 1234 and Input.Field$8==15

```
Transaction ID,Request source,User name,SendMobNum,RecMobNum,ServiceClass,Service,Amount,CreditAmount,Bonus,Process fee
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,15,1,4,1
```

Op#2:

```
Transaction ID,Request source,User name,SendMobNum,RecMobNum,ServiceClass,Service,Amount,CreditAmount,Bonus,Process fee,SendMobNum,Year,Amount,Gender 
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,15,1,4,1,1234,2000,15,Female
```

Example#3:If Input.Field$4 == 1234 and Input.Field$8==60 then print sencond file 1234,2000,60,Female

```
Transaction ID,Request source,User name,SendMobNum,RecMobNum,ServiceClass,Service,Amount,CreditAmount,Bonus,Process fee
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,60,1,4,1
```

Op#3:

```
Transaction ID,Request source,User name,SendMobNum,RecMobNum,ServiceClass,Service,Amount,CreditAmount,Bonus,Process fee,SendMobNum,Year,Amount,Gender 
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,60,1,4,1,1234,2000,60,Female
```

**Update:28 Aug 2014**

Wow , Thanks a lot Ed Morton for very good Hints , Genius !!!
I have tried Trial and Error basis, got below output.
I am getting confuse while using array, not able to understand the array concept, How to debug or check in the command, whether it is accessing first file First line then checking with entire file of second file and so on ...

Attempt#1: ( without $1 & $3 from master.csv)

```
awk '
    BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
    NR == FNR { mob2year[$1]=$2;amt2gender[$3]=$4; next}
    FNR == 1 || ($4 in mob2year && $8 in amt2gender) { print $0,mob2year[$4],amt2gender[$8] }
' Master.txt Input*.txt
```

Output:

```
Transaction ID,Request source,User name,SendMobNum,RecMobNum,ServiceClass,Service,Amount,CreditAmount,Bonus,Process fee,Year,Gender
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1,2000,Male
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3,2000,Female
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1,2001,Male
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3,2001,Female
```

Attempt#2: ( without $1 & $3 from master.csv but populating the info from Input.csv) Would like to know how to print the $1 and $3 from master.csv

```
awk '
    BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
    NR == FNR { mob2year[$1]=$2;amt2gender[$3]=$4; next}
    FNR == 1 || ($4 in mob2year && $8 in amt2gender) { print $0,$4,mob2year[$4],$8,amt2gender[$8] }
' Master.txt Input*.txt
```

Output:

```
Transaction ID,Request source,User name,SendMobNum,RecMobNum,ServiceClass,Service,Amount,CreditAmount,Bonus,Process fee,SendMobNum,Year,Amount,Gender
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1,1234,2000,30,Male
ABCD,SSS,EFG,1234,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3,1234,2000,60,Female
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,30,1,4,1,5678,2001,30,Male
ABCD,SSS,EFG,5678,9999,2345,AB,60,3,6,3,5678,2001,60,Female
```

**Comments:**

```
awk '
    BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }                     'Assign Input/Output separator as ","
    NR == FNR { mob2year[$1]=$2;amt2gender[$3]=$4; next}    'Create array mob2year and store $1 & $2 unique values from Master.txt then  Create array amt2gender and store $3 & $4 unique values from Master.txt
                                    'Read all the lines from Master.txt store into mob2year and amt2gender  
    FNR == 1 || ($4 in mob2year && $8 in amt2gender)        'If NR==1 OR ( $4 from Input.txt in mob2year array  AND $8 from amt2gender ) then 
        { print $0,$4,mob2year[$4],$8,amt2gender[$8] }      'print entire line from Input.txt ($0) , $4 from Input.txt, $8 from Input.txt 
                                    'Not able to understand mob2year[$4] and amt2gender[$8] logic values
' Master.txt Input*.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I REALLY think you can do this on your own, but here's a hint: you want Master.csv treated like 2 different sets of data so populate 2 different arrays from it, `mob2year[$1]=$2` and `amt2gender[$3]=$4`. Now when you read Input.csv just access those via `mob2year[$4]` and `amt2gender[$8]`. Try creating a script on your own using that hint and after testing it update your question with the script and leave a comment if you need help.

Maybe this will help you understand associative arrays:

```
$ cat file1
fruit apple
color red
size large
$
$ cat file2
size fruit garbage color
$
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next} {print $1, a[$1]}' file1 file2
size large
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next} {print $2, a[$2]}' file1 file2
fruit apple
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next} {print $3, a[$3]}' file1 file2
garbage
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next} {print $4, a[$4]}' file1 file2
color red
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next} {print $5, a[$5]}' file1 file2

$
```

Play with the above, add some prints, etc.

Comment: Ed Morton , thanks for the input , sorry i am not getting how to print fields from Master.csv ..

Comment: Ed Morton, would like to treat master.csv as two sets of reference table , One set is first two fields and Another set is 3& 4 th fields

Comment: For example , 
If Input.Field$4 == 1234 and Input.Field$8==30 then print sencond file 1234,2000,30,Male
If Input.Field$4 == 1234 and Input.Field$8==15 then print sencond file 1234,2000,15,Female
If Input.Field$4 == 1234 and Input.Field$8==60 then print sencond file 1234,2000,60,Female

Comment: Ed Morton , i have Edit and provide sample input and output under EDIT , please suggest !!!

Comment: Ed Morton, Thanks a lot Genius and Teacher !!! Have edited my attempts under : Update 28 Aug 2014 , please review and advise !!!

Comment: Ed Morton, Yep, it works they the way I expected the output, For curiosity - would like to know how to print the $1 and $3 field as well from master.csv !

Comment: Ed Morton , if possible , kindly provide some explanation how this script is working for better understanding !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60188/discussion-between-avn-and-ed-morton).

Comment: Ed Morton , Please review and provide your feedback under Comments

Comment: Read this: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Array-Basics. The fields from the first file that you want to use as indices when populating your arrays are fields 1 and 3, and those same values occur in fields 4 and 8 of your second file when you want to use those values as indices to look up the contents of the arrays.

Comment: Ed Morton , Thanks a ton for good support and your patience , proud of your skill and knowledge !!!